# PostgreSQL: Fastest Index For Autocomplete

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table containing one column and 100 million rows of text. 
The text is simple 1 - 5 words sentences.

My goal is to have an ultra-fast query which could be used with an autocomplete. So the user types and I get results as fast as possible.

I tried many different indexes and the `tsvector` feature.

1. What is a good solution/combination for my needs?
2. What other solutions can i use to achieve my goal and an be setup up relativly quick ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to match the complete text with a prefix, the SQL query would be

```
SELECT words FROM phrases WHERE words LIKE 'user input%';
```

A regular B-Tree index with the `text_pattern_ops` operator class should do the trick.

If the phrases are too long to be indexed or you want to save space, index and query just a prefix:

```
CREATE INDEX ON phrases (substr(words, 1, 50) text_pattern_ops);
```

Then query with

```
SELECT words FROM phrases WHERE substr(words, 1, 50) LIKE 'user input%';
```

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz! Do you have a LinkedIn, Facebook or something else for networking?

Comment: I use TCP/IP. You can hire me from https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/

Comment: See the extended answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that OP wanted to autocomplete all words, not just phrases

Comment: Easy - the application can decide that it uses only the current word for searching (truncate at the last space before searching).

Answer (score 1):

The LIKE operator is pitifully slow. Try using BETWEEN as described in [this blog](https://formidable.com/blog/2023/mastering-auto-complete/)